# UIPageViewController Swipe Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have been unable to find a solution to this issue that resolves my case. I am looking to call the two blocks of code that swipe my page view controller programmatically.

Such as a `[self viewControllerAfterViewController:self]` that would call the last block of code.

In `viewDidLoad`

```
[super viewDidLoad];
indexvalue = 1;
NSLog(@"main intitated");

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

ViewController *tvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];
Request *pvc;
viewcontrollers =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tvc, pvc, nil];

[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewcontrollers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

[self addChildViewController:pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:pageViewController.view];

[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Code to swipe between screens called by swipe gesture

```
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexvalue]);

    if (indexvalue == 0 & check0 < 1) {
        check0 = 1;
        ViewController *tvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];
        indexvalue = 1;
        return tvc;
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexvalue]);

    if (indexvalue == 1 & check1 < 1) {
        check1 = 1;
        Request *pvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Friends"];
        indexvalue = 0 ;
        return  pvc;
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
viewcontrollers =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tvc, pvc, nil];

replace with 

viewControllers = @[tvc];
viewControllers= [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
```

Now  add this method

```
- (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    if (index == 0) {
   //first view
    ViewController *pageContentViewController2 = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    return pageContentViewController2;

    }
    //second view

    Request *pageContentViewController3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Request"];
    return pageContentViewController3;
}
```

Comment: How would i call that method from an "ibaction"?

Comment: but your question is not for ibaction you have to desc your problem in question

Comment: - (IBAction)startWalkthrough:(id)sender {
    ViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];
}